# Copy and paste data to a tktable

Tags: r, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit, tktable

I'm using Tcl/Tk to build a GUI, and I would like to know if there is a way to copy and paste data from Excel to a `tktable`?

Right now it is possible if I do column by column, but this is not useful. If there are other ways, please let me know.

Comment: It might be easier to save the sheet out as CSV and load that…

Comment: I take it you have set `-rowseparator` and `-colseparator` to Excel-friendly values?